# Mysterious behavior of echo command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, echo

When we need to use escape sequence characters with `echo` command we must use the `-e` option. Like

```
echo -e "Enter your name : \c"
```

But when we include such kind of statements inside a shell program (.sh file), it produces a mysterious error. It prints

```
-e Enter your name :
```

It doesn't need that `-e` option with echo command as if we write like this

```
echo "Enter your name : \c"
```

It shows output with no errors, but that doesn't work in shell.

So what is the reason? I am using bash shell and Ubuntu 15.04 version.

Answer (score 7):

I guess you haven't used a shebang  (`#! /bin/bash` as the first line of your script). In that case, the script is run using `/bin/sh`, which is `/bin/dash`. And `echo` in `dash` doesn't support the non-standard `-e` (have a look at the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)). You really shouldn't use `echo -e`. Use `printf` instead for far more portable behaviour. See [Why is `printf` better than echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/70524) on Unix and Linux. The following commands should behave identically:

```
bash -c 'printf "%s" "Enter your name"'
dash -c 'printf "%s" "Enter your name"'
```

Comment: +1. `echo` is notoriously non-portable.